# MySQL QUERY HAVING clause not working with WHERE clause

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having issues with having clause and where clause I'm getting below error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'accommodation' in 'where clause'
```

Below is the code:

```
SELECT 
    b.bar_id, b.bar_name, b.bar_image, b.bar_lat, b.bar_lng, 
    b.bar_address, b.bar_phone, b.bar_email, b.bar_open_hours, `category`, 
    ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-37.81829) ) * cos( radians( b.bar_lat ) ) * cos( radians( b.bar_lng ) - radians(144.9620) ) + sin( radians(-37.81829) ) * sin( radians( b.bar_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM 
    bars b 
WHERE 
    `category` LIKE accommodation 
GROUP BY 
    category 
HAVING 
    distance < 500 
ORDER BY 
    distance
```

I cannot figure out why I'm getting this error. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Are you missing single quotes around *accommodation* or is it a valid column name?

Comment: The first step to solving a problem is reading the error message.

Comment: accommodation is the value and category is the column name

Comment: Is 'accommodation' a db field or a string? If it's a string it should be wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: Try reading the error message again.

Comment: Perhaps you don't have a column named `accommodation` in table bars. Check the spelling carefully. Perhaps the column name in table has a typo or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a column called `accommodation`? Or should you be doing a string comparison, in which case it should be `'accommodation'` (surround with single quotes)?

Also you might as well make it

```
`category` = 'accommodation'
```

Since you don't have any wildcards (`%`) in the string.

Comment: I thought I knew SQL but what sense has it to compare 2 unequal strings for equality?

Comment: how to compare strings like above in having clause?

Answer (score 0):

If accommodation is a string value, then you need to wrap it in single quotes. Better yet, there's no need to use LIKE for an exact string, you can use equals instead.

ie:

```
SELECT b.bar_id, b.bar_name, b.bar_image, b.bar_lat, b.bar_lng, b.bar_address, b.bar_phone, b.bar_email, b.bar_open_hours, `category`, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-37.81829) ) * cos( radians( b.bar_lat ) ) * cos( radians( b.bar_lng ) - radians(144.9620) ) + sin( radians(-37.81829) ) * sin( radians( b.bar_lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM bars b WHERE `category` = 'accommodation' GROUP BY category HAVING distance < 500 ORDER BY distance
```